# SAXException with semicolon

Tags: java, sax

I want to parse xml files that have elements like these:

```
<element>&amp</element>
<element>&amp;</element>
```

But SAX Parser is giving me the following exception during parsing:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The reference to entity "amp" must end with the ';' delimiter.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:249)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:208)
```

is there any known workaround for this?

The java code that throws the exception is this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(file);
```

Comment: In what way is that an "escaped semi-colon"? And is that your *actual* XML? A short but complete program demonstrating the problem, along with a sample XML file, would really help.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake. I corrected now my post.

Comment: Please take more care when writing your questions. Sending people off chasing after a problem when you've just mis-typed your question is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this with the XML you've shown (before your edit). Short but complete program:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("test.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(file);
    }
}
```

With a file of:

```
<element>&amp;</element>
```

... it runs with no error.

When the file is just:

```
<element>&amp</element>
```

... it shows the same exception you reported.

My conclusion is that it's correct, and your file *is* broken. Look for every occurrence of `&amp` in the file, and find where it's missing a semi-colon.

Comment: @adranale: Then it's invalid XML. Fix it. And next time, trust what the parser is telling you :)